# Adding a value to ActionController::Parameters on the server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add some value I'm evaluating on the server to the params.

```
  def my_params
    params.require(:my_model).permit(:my_field1, :my_field2, :my_field3)
  end

  def update
    # ..................

    # checking
    my_params["my_value"].class # => ActionController::Parameters
    my_params["my_value"] # => nil

    # adding
    my_params["my_value"] = "my value's value" # => "my value's value"

    # but it's still nil
    my_params["my_value"] # => nil 

    # ..................
  end
```

Why can't I add it into `my_params`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`my_params` is a method not a variable, use an instance variable instead, as below

```
def my_params
    @my_params = params.require(:my_model).permit(:my_field1, :my_field2, :my_field3)
end

def update
  @my_params["my_val"] = "my value"
  #....
end
```

Comment: Just access the params directly... `params[:my_val] = 'my value'`

Comment: @DamienRoche that's bad, since he is whitelisting some params

Comment: ...and where are you whitelisting `my_val`?

Comment: @DamienRoche `params.require(:my_model).permit(:my_field1, :my_field2, :my_field3)` is to whitelist `params` that are not trusted, `my_val` is coming from the server so it is trusted and does not need whitelisting

Comment: @bjhaid I'm afraid you're contradicting yourself. If the controller is setting the param, then why is it "bad, since he is whitelisting some params" because I accessed the `params` directly? There is nothing wrong with `params[:my_val] = 'my value'`.

Comment: In fact, you're code doesn't work. The `@params` instance variable isn't even assigned when you access the `update` method, and you're not permitting `my_val`. Permit `my_val` and simply use `my_params[:my_val] = 'my value'`. No need to assign `@params`.

Comment: @DamienRoche what would be the value of `params` after it has passed through the `my_params` filter???, `my_params` does not mutate `params`, neither should you mutate it to avoid issues with debugging

Comment: Why do you think using `@params` is necessary or even a good idea? http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/4/24/use-params-not-params/

Comment: @DamienRoche have you tested this code before claiming it does not work, the OP most likely has a `before_filter` that calls `my_params`, for me it is that he should use an instance variable that he can reference anywhere call it `@params` or not, your answer uses a method and not an instance variable, methods don't have state, so setting a key on the method does not change the state of the parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54072/discussion-between-bjhaid-and-damien-roche).

Comment: Have you tried to run your code? It doesn't work even with `my_params` called first because you're not permitting `my_val`! Why are you talking about methods and state?

Comment: whoa-ho-ho-ho, let's keep it funny. @DamienRoche here is right. bjhaid, that means you should listen to him.

Comment: I was actually mistaken about mutating params via `my_params[:key] =`, not sure why I received a positive. And @bjhaid does have a good point about not directly accessing `params`. Maybe my Rails install is borked, but `@params[:anykey] = 123; my_params[:anykey]` does not work because `my_params` simple reassigns `@params`. It works if you use `@params ||= [...]` within `my_params` but then allows any key. Yet if you are going to fetch with `@params[:key]`, you might as well use `params[:key]` directly for the above reason (filter is not applied, anyway).