# Rails - ActionController::Parameters include controller value with form values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, actioncontroller

I have a session variable (user_id) that I'd like to include as a foreign key on a record the user is inserting. I have the form values all coming through the form submit to my controller's entity.update(params) method without a problem using the default params definition. That code looks like

```
 def brand_params
    @brand_params = params.require(:brand).permit(:name, :brand_type, :profile_id)
  end
```

The update method looks like

```
if @brand.update(brand_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @brand, notice: 'Widget was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @brand }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @brand.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
```

Now I'd like to append the :profile_id session variable to the @brand_params and following other threads here, I've tried a setter method:

```
def set_brand_params(key, val)
    if @brand_params != nil
      @brand_params[key] = val
    end
  end
```

However, calling this, @brand_params is always nil. Trying to directly add to the brand_params hash doesn't work because it's a better method. If there's a better way to meet this (I'd assume common) use case, I'm all ears! Otherwise, I'd like to know why the var is always nil though in this context, at least the brand_params method sees it as defined and with value. I got this solution in [Adding a value to ActionController::Parameters on the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771125/adding-a-value-to-actioncontrollerparameters-on-the-server-side)

Here is the update method as requested:

```
def update
    puts "update"
    set_brand_params("profile_id", session[:prof])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @brand.update(brand_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @brand, notice: 'Widget was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @brand }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @brand.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: If you are using `set_brand_parmas` before any call of `brand_params` yes, @brand_params is undefined (nil).

Comment: Yes, if I move the @brand_params variable to the constructor (here new()) it's not nil so that's the answer! I'm still unclear on the best practice because now this protected var is public... but good enough.

Comment: Please, can you edit the question and add the whole method update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not agree with merge your data with the params. Because you must permit only the fields you expect your user update. In this case you don't want the user update `profile_id` on brands, and that is a security best practice.

Then brand_params must be:

```
def brand_params
  @brand_params = params.require(:brand).permit(:name, :brand_type)
end
```

Your method update may look by this:

```
def update
  @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
  @brand.assign_attributes(profile_id: session[:prof])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @barnd.update(brand_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @brand, notice: 'Widget was successfully updated.'}
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @brand }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @brand.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

You don't need the method `set_brand_params` at all.

If this don't do the trick, please publish the entry controller, and I hope we find the issue.

edit: add respond_to.

Comment: After I seen your code, I assume you have a before_filter or before_action at your controller, and it sets the @brand variable, like I do at the start of my update method. In this case replace the set_brand_params method with `@brand.assign_attributes(profile_id: session[:prof])`

Comment: Yes, @Alejandro, this worked. By using assign_attributes and removing from the params, this is much more secure. Thanks!